# wordpress 4.0 not uploading images and creates tons of junk files in the library

Tags: wordpress

anyone having issues with uploading images on wordpress 4.0? 
I am getting error anytime attempting images upload. Also, a ton of junk files appeared in my media library all of a sudden...
All the plugins are updated, including WPLM (some indicated it as the solution). 
please see the link to get an idea of what I see in my library...
thanks!﻿
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3i79en1xc78esl6/Screenshot%202014-10-01%2018.41.48.png?dl=0

Comment: I am using WP 4.0 . But I never came across this.

Comment: Could you add details so that your problem can be reproduced, please. Your question is not complete and it is very difficult for anybody to investigate your problem as it is.

Comment: @grdndb this question would fit better here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/    Welcome to the Stack Exchange Multiverse.

Comment: when I tried to upload images I got error html. nothing more... then tons of broken images files in my library and all my images disappeared. I figured out the issue was caused by WPML plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and I found a short of a solution. 
For some reason wordpress 4.0 and WPML Media cause an error to the media library. 
The only thing that seems to resolve the issue is to disable this plugin for now.

Edit
Also I notice this
http://wpml.org/2014/08/wpml-3-1-7-improvements-wordpress-4-0-compatibility/

WPML plugin update will resolve the issue.

Edit 2

I could not find the updated version so I proceed in a custom solution.

I found an older version of WPML Media and in plugin.php I changed the version to 2.1
Then I uploaded the files of the older version to the plugin folder. 
The error with the duplicate images resolved.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was solved after disabling and uninstalling all the WPML plugins.

now I am wondering how to create a multi language website, with my translated posts...